# What is the best method to get rid of a pattern in multiple php files?

Tags: sed, php, xargs

Working on infected website with hundreds of php files with the following injected signature code in the top of each file:

```
<?php /*457563643457563643*/ ?><?php /*5467543654675436*/ ?><?php /*6745833567458335*/ ?><?php /*87934538793453*/ ?>
```

followed by adjacent `<?php` part which has legitimate php code. In other words, the injected code is not on a separate line.

I composed the following code to get rid of the injected code:

```
grep -Rl 457563643457563643 . | xargs sed -i 's/<[?]php.*457563643457563643.*[?]>/<\?php \/\/ RECOVERED FILE \?>/g'
```

which works fine, but unfortunately it also deletes the legitimate php tag that comes just after the injected code.

What would be the best method to get rid of exactly the following part injected in the top of each file:

```
<?php /*457563643457563643*/ ?><?php /*5467543654675436*/ ?><?php /*6745833567458335*/ ?><?php /*87934538793453*/ ?>
```

Comment: Please provide your expected output. Are you trying to remove just the first `<?php /*457563643457563643*/ ?>`? Is this string always the same? (i.e. why use `.*` in your regex?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **best** method is to go to one of your backups from before the intrusion and start from there. It sounds like you want a non-best way. You can use sed to do that.

Using sed, the most straightforward way to remove an exact block of text on a single line is just to use [the `s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) to remove it explicitly:

```
sed -e 's!<?php /\*457563643457563643\*/ ?><?php /\*5467543654675436\*/ ?><?php /\*6745833567458335\*/ ?><?php /\*87934538793453\*/ ?>!!'
```

This just replaces the exact string you quoted with nothing – it's necessary to escape the `*` metacharacter each time, but otherwise this is directly using `s!pattern!replacement!` in the usual manner.

---

I would [use `find -exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) (better, [`-execdir` if you've got it](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html#Deleting-Files)) instead of piping `xargs`, *especially* if I had a directory tree I couldn't trust. There could be filenames with all sorts of things in them, notably newlines, that might lead to executing commands you don't like. For this particular `sed` command line it's unlikely to be an actual problem, but I wouldn't count it out.

You can run the `grep` inside the `find` command and only act on the file if it matches, or just let `sed` handle it anyway - if the pattern doesn't match the file will be the same afterwards anyway.

---

Regardless, I'd still advise caution – these markers aren't the harmful part of things and the bits that are may not be so obvious.

See also: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231/49745)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The `grep -Rl 457563643457563643 .` commands is just fine to get list of infected files. However, running the `grep -Rl 457563643457563643 . | xargs sed -i 's!<\?php /\*457563643457563643\*/ \?><\?php /\*546754365467543636\*/ \?.<\?php /\*6745833567458335\*/ \?><\?php /\*87934538793453\*/ \?>!!'` didn't have any effect.

Comment: After trying different ways this one finally worked: `grep -Rl 457563643457563643 . | xargs sed -i 's!<[?]php.*457563643457563643*.*[?]>!!'` Still I accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the way I found strips extra tags that follow the injected pattern, so I am still in search for the right answer. The answer suggested simply does not work.

Comment: It looks like there were a couple of digits repeated in the command originally, but they're gone now and it works for me.

Comment: So it works if you don't escape question marks as you initially suggested. Thanks a lot!